# Re applying jquery for new fields in nested forms - Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm new to jquery, and i'm using nested forms on rails. The form is so big that I'm trying to apply an accordion plugin to the form. Here is what happens:

The accordion plugin works well as the form is loaded, but, when I add a new field, the accordion won't work with the new field. I believe that I have to make a "refresh", or add something on javascript to jquery find the new field.

Here is the code:

View:

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- wrapper for accordion -->
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :chapters do |builder| %>
        <%= render "chapters_fields", f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p>
        <%= link_to_add_fields "Add chapters", f, :chapters, "chapters" %>
    </p>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Partial _chapters_fields:

```
<div class="chapter-fields">
  <div class="accordionButton">
    <h3>Chapter</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordionContent">
  <p>
    <%= f.input :reference, input_html: {title: "Links chapters to each other. The first chapter must have reference '1'"} %>
    <%= f.input :content, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, style: 'width: 100%' } %>
    <%= f.input :image, input_html: {onchange: "validateFiles(this);"}, data: {max_file_size: 300.kilobytes} %>
    <% if f.object.image.blank? %>
      No current image
    <% else %>
      Current image: <%= f.object.image.url.split("/").last %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
```

Application.js

```
$('.accordionButton').click(function() {
      //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
      $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');
      //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
      $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
      //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
      if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
        $(this).addClass('on');
        //OPEN THE SLIDE
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
      }
 });

    /*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/
    //ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER

    $('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).addClass('over');
      //ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
    }).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('over');
    });

    /*** END REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/
    $('.accordionContent').hide();


function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}

function remove_fields(link, form) {
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
    $(link).closest("."+form+"-fields").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery listeners that your are setting up are listening only the elements of the DOM when the initial document load (I guess you've included this in the `$(document).ready(//your code)` ).

To make them listen new items in a particular container (or inside your entire document), you need to listen at the level above (or to the whole document, like below), like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordionButton', function() {
    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');
    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
      //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
      $(this).addClass('on');
      //OPEN THE SLIDE
      $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }
});

/*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/
//ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER

$(document).on('mouseover', '.accordionButton', function() {
  $(this).addClass('over');
  //ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
});
$(document).on('mouseout', '.accordionButton', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('over');
});

/*** END REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/
$('.accordionContent').hide();


function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}

function remove_fields(link, form) {
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
    $(link).closest("."+form+"-fields").hide();
}
```

That should do the trick.